# rails - 'First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty' with form_for nested object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a basic blogging site in which I want to allow users to offer 'corrections' to posts (just think of it as a comment). The correction object belongs to a post, which in turn belongs to a user (for which I'm using Devise).

I would like the form to create a new correction to be nested in the page for the post,so I'm just rendering the form in posts/show.html.erb with `<% render :template => "corrections/new" %>`. I'm getting a 'First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty' from corrections/new.html.erb though. I think the problem is that the correction isn't being created properly in the new function of its controller.

Here's the new function in corrections_controller:

```
def new
    @correction = current_user.post.new
  end
```

Here's the form in corrections/new.html.erb:

```
<% form_for @correction, html: { multipart: true} do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :correction %>
    <%= f.text_field :correction %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
    resources :posts do
      resources :corrections
      end
    end
```

Basically the problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to create a new corrections object that belongs to the post of the current show page.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new action of the corrections controller you are initializing a post object, not a correction object so first you need to load the post object with a before action callback according to the routes
If the association between post and corrections is with has_many you have to initialize the correction object in the new action by this way

```
before_action load_post

def load_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
end

def new
  @correction = @post.corrections.build
end
```